# Applying MySQL binlogs that are too large

Tags: mysql

I am trying to recover a MySQL crash.  I have data as of Monday and binlogs since then, and want to apply the binlogs as the combination would be a complete set of the data.  The trouble is that binlogs are read as a single packet.  Some of mine are too large, up to 2.4G, while MySQL only allows `max_allowed_packet=1G` (1073741824).  Is there any way to chunk them or otherwise split them up?

Edit: I have now tried the `split` Linux command which gives a "bad magic number" error on the second and subsequent files of each split file.  After reading on this it makes sense.  I have now tried to use `mysqlbinlog --start-position 4 --stop-position 200000003 $1 > $1.binout` so I could use a loop with an increment, but it doesn't end on a boundary:

`WARNING: The range of printed events ends with a row event or a table map event that does not have the STMT_END_F flag set. This might be because the last statement was not fully written to the log, or because you are using a --stop-position or --stop-datetime that refers to an event in the middle of a statement. The event(s) from the partial statement have not been written to output.`

When I increment the next loop is there a way to determine what the real start position is?  The example ended at 199994536.  Is there a way to detect the last position of the resulting binlog?

Comment: Have you tried increasing `max_allowed_packet`?

Comment: You might have more luck with this question over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider 1G is the max for that variable.  I forgot about the dba stack, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: How did you get a 2.4GB binlog in the first place??